# How do i write a java program for the following question?

Tags: java

write a java program to get input as int, float, double, string, diaply the result
I am a beginner and i tried to write it for one value and i am getting lot of error in that

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter int value");
        int value= input.nextint();             
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you wrote so far? What are the error messages?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you please share what errors are you getting?

Comment: We could tell you all of the things that you have done wrong.  However ... I think what you really need to do is go back to your lecture notes or set textbook (or a tutorial) and read about what a Java class *should* look like.  It cannot start with `{` ... for example.  You need a class declaration.

Comment: @Leonard please mention what errors you are getting while running your code.

Comment: And note that **any** character you put in your source code matter. There is a difference between `nextInt()` and `nextint()` ... that difference is what determines whether the compiler complains or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
     int num;
     float fnum;
     String str;
 
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 
     //Get input String
     System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
     str = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Input String is: "+str);
 
     //Get input Integer
     System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
     num = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Input Integer is: "+num);
 
     //Get input float number
     System.out.println("Enter a float number: ");
     fnum = in.nextFloat();
     System.out.println("Input float is: "+fnum);
     
    }
}
```

output:

```
Enter a string: 
siri
Input String is: siri
Enter an integer: 
10
Input Integer is: 10
Enter a float number: 
12.3
Input float is: 12.3
```

jst try it once I think you didn't import util package

Comment: Hint: people learn programming by programming themselves. When you give them their complete assignment ... they only learned that other people are willing to do the hard work for them. If you really want to help, give HINTS, not complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Getting int input
        System.out.print("Enter int: ");
        int myInt = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Int entered = " + myInt);

        // Getting float input
        System.out.print("Enter float: ");
        float myFloat = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Float entered = " + myFloat);
    
        // Getting double input
        System.out.print("Enter double: ");
        double myDouble = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Double entered = " + myDouble);
    
        // Getting String input
        System.out.print("Enter text: ");
        String myString = input.next();
        System.out.println("Text entered = " + myString);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter int: 5
Int entered = 5
Enter float: 5.3
Float entered = 5.3
Enter double: -1.1
Double entered = -1.1
Enter text: Hello World!
Text entered = Hello World!
```